# Android deep-links - Error 1024 when in debug/emulator

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I have added my assetlinks.json to my website within the .well-known folder and confirmed the file is being served

```
[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.******.*********",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
      ["23:DB:...."]
    }
  }]
```

I have added auto verify and data tags to the AndroidManifest.xml though as it is a capacitor application I wasn't 100% which intent-filter to add it to

```
<application>
        <activity>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host=*****.*******.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The deep linking works fine when I manually add it within the phone/emulator but does not seem to "auto verify".

I tried the following adb commands

```
adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify com.*****.*******
```

then

```
adb shell pm get-app-links com.****.*******
```

And get back

```
com.*****.******:
    ID: b5eb46a8-eb37-44ff-8b50-c6bc92402d34
    Signatures: [23:DB:....]
    Domain verification state:
      *****.*****.com: 1024
```

I suppose my first question is - Should I even expect this to work with the application running in debug (unpublished/signed) and if so - any help?

Answer (score 0):

according to the android app, link documentation: Do not publish your app with dev/test URLs in the manifest file that may not be accessible to the public (such as any that are accessible only with a VPN). A work-around in such cases is to configure build variants to generate a different manifest file for dev builds.